# What type of component would be required?

Tags: microcontroller

I apologize in advance if this is the wrong place to ask the question.  Although it does in someway relate to electrical engineering, at the product level, i am sure. Basically i am trying to figure at the feasibility of a starting product that i might sell.

The product would basically be a car door magnet as illustrated here: http://www.vistaprint.co.uk/car-door-magnets.aspx?&GP=8%2f8%2f2013+9%3a03%3a56+PM&GPS=2921082194&GNF=0.  My question is what kind of electrical component would be needed that could somehow record the moment the magnet becomes detached from the surface?  What name is given to such a device, so i can further research it?

Comment: I think a [reed switch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed_switch) might help.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to measure (static) magnetic fields is to use a Hall effect sensor.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_effect_sensor

They are typically used for position sensing, and it is possible to get either analog sensors (which measure the strength of the field, which may correspond to distance) or digital sensors, which just measure if the field exceeds a threshold.

Comment: Could these easily be added to a car magnet do you think?  Furthermore, are they expensive? Cheers

Comment: My intuition is that it would be easier to attach to the car body to detect when a magnet becomes detached. It's probably possible to place on the magnet as well (presumably when the magnet is attached to the car, most of the magnetic field will go through the metal in the car as opposed to the sensor). Sensors are very cheap, and available as commodities, on the order of cents in qty, of course the cost would come from engineering the rest of the system (presumably it would need a micro-controller and some sort of indicator and some analog to read from the sensor).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing to try is a reed switch: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed_switch

Obviously, the magnet which operates it has to be strong enough and close enough, but it's the simplest thing which could be possibly work.

If you want to experiment with a Hall effect sensor, you could do worse than playing with a TI SensorTag - it's a ready-made thing with (inter alia) a 3D magnetic field sensor, and an iPhone app which displays the results.

Answer (score 0):

Why should be a magnetic sensor specifically used? If all you want is sensing whether the "device" is attached/detached you could use a mechanical swich of some sort, always try to avoid complexity.

Comment: A "magnetic sensor" could actually be a simple [reed switch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed_switch): a two-terminal part that costs pennies and contains a mechanical switch, enclosed in an evacuated glass vial, activated by a magnetic field.